# How to read all the messages from a SQS ,aggregate all those msgs and store them as a single JSON file to S3 bucket, using lambda Java SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to read all the messages from a SQS  ,aggregate all those msgs and store them as a single JSON file to S3 bucket, using lambda Java SDK?

Following Steps are involved in my implementation

1. Create a Standard SQS and send 500 messages to that SQS
2. Write a lambda read all the messages from that SQS using while loop(until message count becomes zero)
3. After reading all the messages from that SQS, now this lambda will have to aggregate all those received messages in to an ArrayList and convert the arraylist as a single JSON file and store this JSON file at a S3 bucket

now i am stuck at step 3, as AWS spans out multiple lambda instances while reading the SQS messages, hence i am unable to aggregate the received messages at one ArrayList, should i use Dynamo DB to aggregate all the messages and create a single JSON file and store in S3 bucket?

Please suggest a solution to resolve this problem

Thanks,
Sundar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `ReservedConcurrentExecutions` attribute in your Lambda function to 1, therefore avoiding multiple instances to spin up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is more fitting for a [Kinesis Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/introduction.html)

A stream is essentially a queue but has some important differences, mainly in your scenario those differences are the batch size that a Lambda can take from Kinesis is capped at 10000 events or 6mb, rather than 10 events like in SQS. You can simply create a Kinesis stream with 1 shard, which would mean only 1 Lambda will be running and it will be reading the data synchronously. If you do it this way then you don't have to read from SQS in small batches, and don't have to worry about multiple Lambda instances

Some useful reference: [Using Lambda with Kinesis as an event source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html)

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to read the messages in batches nor to use SQS Triggers for Lambda. The OP clearly states to have a while loop reading 500 messages (and this is totally possible if the Lambda function is polling the SQS queue). Whether these 500 messages come in 50 batches of 10 or in 500 batches of 1, that's another story.

Comment: OP mentioned their implementation for it, I'm simply suggesting a different implementation that would solve their problem in a simpler, more efficient way. If OP was only aware of SQS, the reason they had to implement a while loop was because you can't have a large batch size trigger from SQS, but it is very easy to setup a trigger from Kinesis that polls from the stream in batches of 500.